# mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Is it possible to refer to the values from the INSERT statement as an entity rather than one field at a time?

Tags: mysql

I haven't found a syntax to do this, what I find frustrating is that I haven't seen anything that specifically says it can't be done, so I keep searching.

With a table "table_one", with one unique field "table_one.a" which is the primary key, is it possible to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table_one` (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUES();
```

I'm aware of the following approaches:

```
INSERT INTO `table_one` (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `b` = '2', `c` = '3', `d` = '4', `e` = '5', `f` = '6', `g` = '7', `h` = '8';
```

And

```
INSERT INTO `table_one` (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `b` = 'VALUES(b)', `c` = 'VALUES(c)', `d` = 'VALUES(d)', `e` = 'VALUES(e)', `f` = 'VALUES(f)', `g` = 'VALUES(g)', `h` = 'VALUES(h)';
```

I'm hoping that (if it's not possible) someone can point me to a reference that explains why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible because it violates the `UPDATE` syntax, so you must list every column.  You may look into using `REPLACE INTO`, but be careful as that actually deletes the row and adds it again, so you may lose some values -- it also triggers foreign key `ON DELETE`s.  However, it is a much less verbose way to do what you want.

Comment: That you can use VALUES with REPLACE INTO is the reason it bothers me that you can't with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. I'll accept "what is" and move on with a little less weight on my shoulders. Good job mentioning the pitfalls of using REPLACE INTO.

Answer (score 1):

No, [it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537710/is-there-a-way-to-use-on-duplicate-key-to-update-all-that-i-wanted-to-insert/9537799#9537799).

There is no reference that explains why: there is simply no syntax that allows you to do it.

Comment: I spent hours searching for info about this question, feeling a bit awkward about missing such a similar request.