# MySQL insert on duplicate update for non-PRIMARY key

Tags: mysql

I am little confused with insert on duplicate update query. 
I have MySQL table with structure like this:

- record_id (PRIMARY, UNIQUE)
- person_id (UNIQUE)
- some_text
- some_other_text

I want to update some_text and some_other_text values for person if it's id exists in my table.person or insert new record in this table otherwise. How it can be done if person_id is not PRIMARY?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need a query that check if exists any row with you record_id (or person_id). If exists update it, else insert new row

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table.person WHERE record_id='SomeValue')
    UPDATE table.person 
    SET some_text='new_some_text', some_other_text='some_other_text' 
    WHERE record_id='old_record_id'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO table.person (record_id, person_id, some_text, some_other_text) 
    VALUES ('new_record_id', 'new_person_id', 'new_some_text', 'new_some_other_text')
```

Another better approach is

```
UPDATE table.person SET (...) WHERE person_id='SomeValue'
IF ROW_COUNT()=0
    INSERT INTO table.person (...) VALUES (...)
```

Comment: [@@ROWCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) or [ROW_COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)?

Comment: @@ROW_COUNT() sorry. @@ROWCOUNT is for SQL Server @wchiquito

Comment: @fattidare checking if exist is another working solution - it is ok, thank you

Comment: Your second approach is an excellent idea. `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE` **`PRIMARY`** `KEY UPDATE` is truly a missing feature in my experience.

Comment: As it turns out, **the conditional query will only work in a stored procedure**. I have found an alternative that works in regular queries and will post a separate answer here.

Comment: **Note** that `ROW_COUNT()` will return `0` if you try to update the post with the same values, causing duplicate posts.

Comment: is it just me or is this missing a `THEN` before the `UPDATE` statement?

Answer (score 13):

Your question is very valid. This is a very common requirement. And most people get it wrong, due to what MySQL offers.

- The requirement: **Insert unless the `PRIMARY` key exists, otherwise update**.
- The common approach: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
- The result of that approach, disturbingly: **Insert unless the `PRIMARY` *or any `UNIQUE` key* exists, otherwise update**!

What can go horribly wrong with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? You insert a supposedly new record, with a new `PRIMARY` key value (say a UUID), but you happen to have a duplicate value for its `UNIQUE` key.

What you want is a proper exception, indicating that you are trying to insert a duplicate into a `UNIQUE` column.

But what you get is an unwanted `UPDATE`! MySQL will take the conflicting record and start overwriting its values. If this happens unintentionally, you have mutilated an old record, and any incoming references to the old record are now referencing the new record. And since you probably won't tell the query to update the `PRIMARY` column, your new UUID is nowhere to be found. If you ever encounter this data, it will probably make no sense and you will have no idea where it came from.

We need a solution to *actually* **insert unless the `PRIMARY` key exists, otherwise update**.

We will use a query that consists of two statements:

1. Update where the `PRIMARY` key value matches (affects 0 or 1 rows).
2. Insert if the `PRIMARY` key value does not exist (inserts 1 or 0 rows).

This is the query:

```
UPDATE my_table SET
unique_name = 'one', update_datetime = NOW()
WHERE id = 1;

INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT 1, 'one', NOW()
FROM my_table
WHERE id = 1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0;
```

Only one of these queries will have an effect. The `UPDATE` is easy. As for the `INSERT`: `WHERE id = 1` results in a row if the id exists, or no row if it does not. `HAVING COUNT(*) = 0` inverts that, resulting in a row if the id is new, or no row if it already exists.

I have explored other variants of the same idea, such as with a `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE`, but they all looked more convoluted. Improvements are welcome.

Comment: I'm getting deadlocks on insert with this approach using MariaDB, two transactions racing for locks.

Comment: @jarnoan Two questions: (1) Are you submitting this as a single query or multiple? I recommend passing it as one. (2) Are you using a database transaction? If so, with which isolation level?

Comment: (1) Multiple, one for update and another for insert. (2) Yes, using transaction with default isolation level (that would be repeatable read for innodb, I suppose). I do have another where clause in update statement, and this is a Galera cluster (but writes using the same server instance), so that might cause something.

Comment: @jarnoan Galera cluster: bingo. Sending it as a single query should solve your problem. Sends it to the same node. If you **really** can't: This is a huge subject for a comment but here goes. **Always** set your cluster to have 1 write node. This prevents fail-on-commit (which is hell). Preferably, also enable causal reads (`wsrep_sync_wait`) for _all_ query types, including selects. Doing so enables "causal reads": if you write-then-read, it prevents you from seeing stale data, and ensures you get what you expect. (Because if your database is hard to reason about, you're in trouble.)

Answer (score 11):

> [13.2.5.3 INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
>
> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL
>   performs an UPDATE of the old row.

Example:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_upsert`//
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_test`//

CREATE TABLE `table_test` (
  `record_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `person_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `some_text` VARCHAR(50),
  `some_other_text` VARCHAR(50),
  UNIQUE KEY `record_id_index` (`record_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `person_id_index` (`person_id`)
)//

INSERT INTO `table_test`
  (`person_id`, `some_text`, `some_other_text`)
VALUES
  (1, 'AAA', 'XXX'),
  (2, 'BBB', 'YYY'),
  (3, 'CCC', 'ZZZ')//

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_upsert`(
  `p_person_id` INT UNSIGNED,
  `p_some_text` VARCHAR(50),
  `p_some_other_text` VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `table_test`
    (`person_id`, `some_text`, `some_other_text`)
  VALUES
    (`p_person_id`, `p_some_text`, `p_some_other_text`)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `some_text` = `p_some_text`,
                          `some_other_text` = `p_some_other_text`;
END//

DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `sp_upsert`(1, 'update_text_0', 'update_text_1');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `record_id`,
    ->   `person_id`,
    ->   `some_text`,
    ->   `some_other_text`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table_test`;
+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| record_id | person_id | some_text     | some_other_text |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|         1 |         1 | update_text_0 | update_text_1   |
|         2 |         2 | BBB           | YYY             |
|         3 |         3 | CCC           | ZZZ             |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `sp_upsert`(4, 'new_text_0', 'new_text_1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `record_id`,
    ->   `person_id`,
    ->   `some_text`,
    ->   `some_other_text`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table_test`;
+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| record_id | person_id | some_text     | some_other_text |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
|         1 |         1 | update_text_0 | update_text_1   |
|         2 |         2 | BBB           | YYY             |
|         3 |         3 | CCC           | ZZZ             |
|         5 |         4 | new_text_0    | new_text_1      |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d13dc7/1)</kbd>

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. It is more efficient and it does fit into MySQL approved way to do it.

Comment: It's a very good answer, but only applies if there's a unique index present, which isn't always desirable.

Comment: @mahemoff you can also use `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_idx
ON table1(column1, column2, column3,...);` to specify multiple columns to be unique  for the row, which means all values of `column1, column2, column3,...` must be same to be duplicate in this way. (Thus these columns can have same values to some extent.) And, if the row is duplicate, that triggers the update.

Comment: If same value as the ones specified by the `values` should be saved on the duplicates, this can also be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383503/on-duplicate-key-update-same-as-insert

Answer (score 2):

How about my approach?

Let's say you have one table with a autoincrement id and three text-columns. You want to insert/update the value of column3 with the values in column1 and column2 being a (non unique) key.

I use this query (without explicitly locking the table):

```
insert into myTable (id, col1, col2, col3)
select tmp.id, 'col1data', 'col2data', 'col3data' from
(select id from myTable where col1 = 'col1data' and col2 = 'col2data' union select null as id limit 1) tmp
on duplicate key update col3 = values(col3)
```

Anything wrong with that? For me it works the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

A flexible solution should retain the atomicity offered by `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and work regardless of if it's `autocommit=true` and not depend on a transaction with an isolation level of `REPEATABLE READ` or greater.

Any solution performing check-then-act across multiple statements would not satisfy this.

Here are the options:

#### If there tends to be more inserts than updates:

```
INSERT INTO table (record_id, ..., some_text, some_other_text) VALUES (...);

IF <duplicate entry for primary key error>
  UPDATE table SET some_text = ..., some_other_text = ... WHERE record_id = ...;

  IF affected-rows = 0
    -- retry from INSERT OR ignore this conflict and defer to the other session
```

#### If there tends to be more updates than inserts:

```
UPDATE table SET some_text = ..., some_other_text = ... WHERE record_id = ...;

IF affected-rows = 0
  INSERT INTO table (record_id, ..., some_text, some_other_text) VALUES (...);

  IF <duplicate entry for primary key error>
    -- retry from UPDATE OR ignore this conflict and defer to the other session
```

#### If you don't mind a bit of ugliness, you can actually use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and do this in a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO table (record_id, ..., some_text, some_other_text) VALUES (...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      some_text = if(record_id = VALUES(record_id), VALUES(some_text), some_text),
      some_other_text = if(record_id = VALUES(record_id), VALUES(some_other_text), some_other_text)

IF affected-rows = 0
  -- handle this as a unique check constraint violation
```

Note: `affected-rows` in these examples mean *affected* rows and not *found* rows.  The two can be confused because [a single parameter switches which of these values the client is returned](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html).

Also note, if `some_text` and `some_other_text` are not actually modified (and the record is not otherwise changed) when you perform the update, those checks on `affected-rows = 0` will misfire.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post because I needed what's written in the title, and I found a pretty handy solution, but no one mentioned it here, so I thought of pasting it here. Note that this solution is very handy if you're initiating your database tables. In this case, when you create your corresponding table, define your primary key etc. as usual, and for the combination of columns you want to be unique, simply add

```
UNIQUE(column_name1,column_name2,...)
```

at the end of your `CREATE TABLE` statement, for any combination of the specified columns you want to be unique. Like this, according to [this page here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/), "MySQL uses the combination of values in both column column_name1 and column_name2 to evaluate the uniqueness", and reports an error if you try to make an insert which already has the combination of values for column_name1 and column_name2 you provide in your insert. Combining this way of creating a database table with the corresponding `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax appeared to be the most suitable solution for me. Just need to think of it carefully before you actually start using your table; when setting up your database tables.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, like me, who is a DB noob....the above things didn't work for me. I have a primary key and a unique key... And I wanted to insert if unique key didn't exist. After a LOT of Stack Overflow and Google searching, I found not many results for this... but I did find a site that gave me a working answer: https://thispointer.com/insert-record-if-not-exists-in-mysql/

And for ease of reading here is my answer from that site:

```
INSERT INTO table (unique_key_column_name)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'unique_value' AS unique_key_column_name) AS temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
     SELECT unique_key_column_name FROM table
     WHERE unique_key_column_name = 'unique_value'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Please also note the `'` marks are wrapped around for me because I use string in this case.