# INSERT IGNORE INTO multiple rows but on fail UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert, insert-update

I have this `customer` table:

- `id` = primary key
- `driver_id` = unique int
- `user_id` = foreign key to another table

Table:

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | driver_id | user_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 |    111111 |       4 |
|  2 |   1212121 |      23 |
|  3 |    412444 |      21 |
|  4 |     12341 |      21 |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

I have to insert multiple rows at once. However, I understand if I use `INSERT INTO IGNORE` and a `driver_id` already exists it won't add it. However, I want it so, if `driver_id` already exists, it updates the `user_id`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO customer (driver_id, user_id) VALUES
(5555, 43),
(111111, 63)
```

Therefore the end table would look like the following because it inserts the `driver_id` `5555` and updates the `driver_id` `111111` to `user_id` `63`:

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | driver_id | user_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 |    111111 |      63 |
|  2 |   1212121 |      23 |
|  3 |    412444 |      21 |
|  4 |     12341 |      21 |
|  5 |      5555 |      43 |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

How can I achieve this? So [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)  doesn't answer my question is because this is on duplicate key. However, `id` is a key and `user_id` is a key. One `user_id` may have multiple `driver_id`'s. Using `INSERT ON DUPLICATE` doesn't let me pick a specific key to update on. What would I do?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495194/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-update-for-non-primary-key

Comment: @SABER-FICTIONALCHARACTER Thats for one query. I want to bulk insert/update

Comment: As MySQL documentation says: "If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs". So you can add UNIQUE index on any field or combination of fields and use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE`