# Yii2 - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 on insert batch

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I am using this code for inserting batch:

```
$db  = Yii::$app->db;
$sql = $db->queryBuilder->batchInsert('components', ["name"], $components);
$db->createCommand($sql . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE')->execute();
```

And I am getting this error: **SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064**. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax at the end of the query. See examples at [On Duplicate Key Update same as insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383503/on-duplicate-key-update-same-as-insert)