# Is InnoDB neccessary for this case?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have been looking for the answer to the question below:

[MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

I have an extra question to the accepted answer. However, I don't have enough reputation to comment on the page...

In the answer, Mike create the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_listnames` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tele` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Is InnoDB a must, according to the query issued below? (also quoted from the answer)

```
INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'John', 'Doe', '022') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE name = 'John'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Thanks.

Comment: No, InnoDB is not required. But it is now the default. MyISAM does not support ACID.

Comment: Thank you! I like StackOverflow - members like you are always eager to help and I have my answer within 5 minutes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary.

But I prefer to write your query this way:

```
INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele)
SELECT 'John', 'Doe', '022' FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE name = 'John'
);
```

or even better, set an unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE table_listnames ADD UNIQUE (name)
```

and just insert with this:

```
INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', '022')
```

if a row with the name John is already present, the INSERT will simply fail.

Comment: Oh thanks for your suggestion! The variable concerned is already `UNIQUE`. I just want to know if there's duplicate. If it is so, I have to get the key of that row... and talking about detecting duplicates, after some more search, I find out that `on duplicate update keys` does both jobs in mysql... is that right?

Comment: @ChungLunYuen yes, if you want to INSERT a new record when the name is not present, or UPDATE an existing one you have to set a UNIQUE constraint and use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE ... see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383503/on-duplicate-key-update-same-as-insert