# INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with multiple keys

Tags: mysql, indexing, upsert

I have this table with the following columns:

```
id
userid
app
field
value
```

The columns "field" and "app" are unique together to the "userid". So the user will always only have 1 row that has the same "app" and "field" values together. But they will have more then one row that has just the "app" value the same or just the "field" value the same. And there will always be multiple rows with the same "userid".

I am not sure how i can do and insert or update on multiple keys. I  can't set them as unique in mysql as the value can be used for other "userid" rows or other rows that has a different "app" or "field" value.

Is this possible or will i have to do a SELECT first to check if a row exists where the "userid", "app" and "field" match what i am wanting to insert or update.

Also, i am trying to insert/update more then 1 row with a single query.

Comment: cant you create (userid,app,field) as unique

Comment: The purpose of the unique constraint is so that MySQL will reject any inserts which violate it.

Comment: In short.... I want to insert a row with columns "userid", "app" and "field"  but if there is already a row with those 3 having the same value then it will update that row. If one of those is different meaning now other row maches, then it will insert it.

Comment: Hi Mahesh, none of those can be unique because the value may be used again for another row.

Comment: You can  use insert into with on duplicate key update statment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Duplicate Key Update same as insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383503/on-duplicate-key-update-same-as-insert)

Comment: You need to SELECT first for checking if one of them are exists or not than you probably do insertion or updation

Comment: You are missing the point, what @MaheshMadushanka is saying, is that you can create a unique index on multiple fields, not 3 indices on 3 separate fields.That matches your requirements exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me...

```
INSERT INTO table (field, app, userid, value)
           VALUES (1,1,1,1),(2,2,2,2),(3,3,3,3),(4,4,4,4)
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=VALUES(value);
```

this works doing multiple rows with a single query

Comment: _And_ have that 3-column `UNIQUE` key.

Answer (score 3):

First create a unique index on `(user_id, app, field)`.

```
ALTER TABLE user_settings
ADD UNIQUE (userid,app,field);
```

then use a query like this.

```
INSERT INTO user_settings SET
       -- id = ?,   Do not include this -- you don't have the value
       userid = ?,
        app=?,
        field=?,
        value = ?,
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        value = ?;
```

Comment: I created the new unique with 3 columns, i just tried this but it didn't create a new one, it updated one with a different userid

INSERT INTO user_settings (field, app, userid, value) VALUES('approvaldefaultyes','apdible_servicebar',1,'1'),('emailcustomerdefaultyes','apdible_servicebar',1,'1') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
    value = VALUES(value)

Comment: try it with above mention query in answer (replace question marks with your values)

Comment: sorry pasted wrong one, this is the one but i am not sure it is working when i do multiple SET ( if that is possible? )...... INSERT INTO user_settings SET (field = 'approvaldefaultyes', app = 'apdible_servicebar', userid = 1, value = '1'),(field = 'emailcustomerdefaultyes', app = 'apdible_servicebar', userid = 1, value = '1') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
    value = valuedead

Comment: soory i coudnt get your point what do you mean by multiple set

Comment: well i am trying to insert or update 2 rows at the same time there.  i guess i forgot to mention it above that i will always be inserting/update more then 1 row at once

Comment: no you cant do it with above . if your doing it you have to do it one by one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115710/discussion-between-mahesh-madushanka-and-pixelpaul).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
update mytable set col1 = @value where (field = @v and app=@v1)
```

if you want the three fields then:

```
 update mytable set col1 = @value where (field = @v and app=@v1 and userid = @v2)
```

you should make sure that the fields needed are joined with 'and' and all are enclosed in brackets

Comment: sorry, how does this insert the row if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: this for update..to insert you should select : select * from mytable where (field = @v and app=@v1 and userid = @v2)..if there is a result returned then update using what i wrote in the answer..else insert normally as u r sure now that this is a new data