# ms access insert into no duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion

I need to insert into an access database. But skip the row if column dup is already in the table.

What I have so far is this:

```
<cfoutput  query="hours">
<cfquery name="Employee" datasource="test">

INSERT INTO Tbl_Hours_Comments
(ID, ship_num, dup)
    values(#hours.id#, #hours.ship#, #hours.dup#)
</cfquery>
</cfoutput>
```

If I don't make dup a Primary Key. Then it will INSERT duplicates. If I make dup a Primary Key. Then I get an error.

I think I need something like MySQL. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Or maybe dup_val_on_index exception handling like in Oracle.

@Gord Thompson

I tried (Not sure if I'm doing it right):

```
<cfoutput  query="hours">
<cfquery name="Insert_Employee" datasource="trung">
INSERT Tbl_Hours_Comments (ID, ship_num, dup)

values(#hours.id#, #hours.ship#, #hours.dup#)
SELECT ? as dup
  FROM( SELECT COUNT(*) as n from Tbl_Hours_Comments) as Dual



WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT *
            FROM Tbl_Hours_Comments
            WHERE dup = ?
        )


</cfquery>
</cfoutput>
```

But I get [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect .

What are the ? in your select statement?

Comment: If this were VBA, could turn off the warnings with `Set Warnings False` run the SQL and then `Set Warnings True` or use CurrentDb.Execute. Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383503/on-duplicate-key-update-same-as-insert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Duplicate Key Update same as insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383503/on-duplicate-key-update-same-as-insert)

Comment: What is the source of the data in the "hours" query? If it is from a table in the same database, it is a LOT more efficient to skip the cfloop and use a single `insert into / select ... from ...` statement containing a `where not exists...` clause.

Comment: hours is from a cf query of a query. The data is in another data source.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean another *table* within that same MS Access database? Or a totally separate database? If so, which type - MS Access, SQL Server, etcetera? MS Access supports [querying external databases](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IN-Clause-3F9369A8-2032-4637-81AF-699DB411FBFA).

Comment: Totally separate DB. It's an Oracel database.

Comment: Okay, [the docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722917.aspx) Oracle is a supported type, so I would give it a whirl.

Comment: Thanks I will try it. In your example Ex is the hours table?

Comment: (Edit) The "ex" is a [table alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)). See also my updated answer.

Comment: *"What are the ? in your select statement?"* - They are parameter placeholders. The parameter values in `params` are substituted for the placeholders when the query is executed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Microsoft Access ODBC driver to update the database then you can use `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS`. The following example is in Python, but it looks like you should be able to do something similar in ColdFusion.

```python
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=db1")  # Microsoft Access ODBC
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

hours_ship = "ship102"  # test data
hours_dup = 3           #

sql = """\
INSERT INTO Tbl_Hours_Comments (ship_num, dup)
SELECT ? as ship_num, ? AS dup
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Tbl_Hours_Comments) AS Dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tbl_Hours_Comments WHERE dup = ?)
"""
params = (hours_ship, hours_dup, hours_dup)
crsr.execute(sql, params)
cnxn.commit()
print("{} row(s) inserted".format(crsr.rowcount))
crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Note that this approach will *not* work using the Microsoft Access OLEDB provider.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would it not work with OLEDB?

Comment: @Leigh - I don't know for sure, it's just one of the subtle differences between the Access ODBC driver and the Access OLEDB provider.

Comment: Good to know. Been a while since I have used OLEDB. Never really got the hang of all the differences, beyond knowing there are some :)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

If for some reason you cannot query the external database directly, try using a variation on [Gord Thompson's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43430384/104223). It is not as efficient as INSERT /SELECT .. FROM Table, but ... will work with MS Access.

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_Hours_Comments (ID, ship_num, dup)
SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#hours.id#" cfsqltype="(your column type here)">
       , <cfqueryparam value="#hours.ship#" cfsqltype="(your column type here)">
       , <cfqueryparam value="#hours.dup#" cfsqltype="(your column type here)">
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
          SELECT NULL
          FROM   Tbl_Hours_Comments dupe
          WHERE  dupe.id = <cfqueryparam value="#hours.id#" cfsqltype="(your column type here)">
          AND    dupe.ship = <cfqueryparam value="#hours.ship#" cfsqltype="(your column type here)">
          AND    dupe.dup = <cfqueryparam value="#hours.dup#" cfsqltype="(your column type here)">
       )
```

---

What is the source of the data in the "hours" query? MS Access supports querying certain [external databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177907(v=office.12).aspx) (MS Access, SQL Server, Excel, ecetera) directly using an IN clause. Example:

```
 SELECT Column1, Column2
 FROM   TableName IN 'c:\path\to\external.mdb'
```

So if the data is from a (supported) external database OR another table within the same database, it is a LOT more efficient to skip the `cfloop` and run a *single* INSERT INTO / SELECT query. Just combine it with an OUTER JOIN or NOT EXISTS clause to exclude records that are already exist in the target table.

Disclaimer - I have not used Access in a long while, but the syntax should be something like this:

**Option #1 - OUTER JOIN**

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_Hours_Comments (ID, ship_num, dup)
SELECT ex.id, ex.ship, ex.dup
FROM   OtherTable ex LEFT JOIN Tbl_Hours_Comments dupe
          ON dupe.id = ex.id
          AND dupe.ship = ex.ship
          AND dupe.dup = ex.dup
WHERE  dupe.id IS NULL
```

**Option #2 - NOT EXISTS**

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_Hours_Comments (ID, ship_num, dup)
SELECT ex.id, ex.ship, ex.dup
FROM   OtherTable ex
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
          SELECT NULL
          FROM   Tbl_Hours_Comments dupe
          WHERE  dupe.id = ex.id
          AND    dupe.ship = ex.ship
          AND    dupe.dup = ex.dup
       )
```

Comment: (Edit) In theory, but .. I do not have Access installed anymore, so I cannot verify it. Give it a try. Skip the INSERT part for now and just see if either of the SELECT statements works.

Comment: BTW, the concept is sound and this would definitely work with tables in the same database. However, from what I remember MS Access has some limitations regarding cross db queries, so it is possible this is not supported.

Comment: *"MS Access has some limitations regarding cross db queries"* - It does, but if the Access database contains an ODBC linked table that points to the external table then it behaves very much like a local table. ("Some conditions apply. Your mileage may vary. And so on." :)

Comment: @GordThompson - Ooh... forgot about those. So "in theory" they could link to the remote table and the INSERT / SELECT *should* work. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post what I ended up doing in case it helps someone.

Thank you to @Leigh and @Gord for help on this problem.

This what I finally did to solve it. It is very similar to Leigh and Gord's way of a sub query.

I CFQUERY both tables (QueryA and QueryB).

Then I used this (from https://coldfusionblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/how-to-do-an-outer-join-in-query-of-queries/):

```
<cfquery name="unique">
SELECT *
FROM QueryA
WHERE QueryA.ID NOT IN (#ValueList(QueryB.ID)#)
</cfquery>
```

To get a list of element in QueryA that are not in QueryB.

Then I used another insert query to insert all the new unique elements into QueryB.

Comment: Thanks for posting your final code. Though they look similar, the QoQ's approach uses CF memory rather than off-loading the work to the database (usually better equipped for the job). Also, keep in mind a `where not in (....)` clause tends to slow down the more items there are in the list. So you might still want to investigate the "linked query" and/or "external database" options to see if it is more efficient. Especially if the final `insert` query involves a loop to add one record at a time. While sometimes unavoidable, looping tends to be the slowest method of inserting data...