# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in prepared statement with array

Tags: php, mysql

My code so far:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO articles(id, name, picture, url, origAmount, currAmount, added) VALUES ';

$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();

$date = getDate();

foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $insertQuery[] = '(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    $insertData[] = $article->id;
    $insertData[] = $article->name;
    $insertData[] = $article->picture;
    $insertData[] = $article->url;
    $insertData[] = $article->amount;
    $insertData[] = $article->amount;
    $insertData[] = $date['year'] . '-' . $date['mon'] . '-' . $date['mday'];
}

if(!empty($insertQuery)) {          
    $query .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
    $handle = $this->link->prepare($query);
    $handle->execute($insertData);
}
```

If the id already exists I want to update only currAmount. 
I have tried

```
$insertQuery[] = '(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE currAmount = (currAmount)';
```

which gives

'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 [...] near '('0192801635','The Renaissance A Ve' at line 1'

So the literal content of the row, it inserted fine on the empty table though, so it's not a problem with the content per se.

How can I do this?

EDIT: SOLVED IT

After the implode, added

```
$query .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE currAmount = VALUES(currAmount)';
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: how do you know that the certain id already exists

Comment: @jeroen it seems to work for [this guy](https://www.tutorials.de/threads/mysql-insert-mit-duplicate-key-update.394298/), but he put the values in by hand, which I can't do.

Comment: @AnilShrestha I looked it up in the table

Comment: since your insertquery is an array you have to use foreach loop and execute single query at a time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Duplicate Key Update same as insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383503/on-duplicate-key-update-same-as-insert)

Comment: You can use REPLACE. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

```
... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE currAmount=values(currAmount)
```

You forgot to add values keyword

**UPDATE**
Full example:

`$insertQuery[] = '(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE currAmount=values(currAmount)';`

Comment: "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; [...] near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUE(currAmount)" :(

Comment: I did not want to write whole query, so I replaced unchanged SQL by ...

Answer (score -1):

DO something like this

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {
  $insertQuery = '(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE currAmount = (currAmount)';
  $insertData = $article->id;
  $insertData = $article->name;
  $insertData = $article->picture;
  $insertData = $article->url;
  $insertData = $article->amount;
  $insertData = $article->amount;
  $insertData = $date['year'] . '-' . $date['mon'] . '-' . $date['mday'];

  if(!empty($insertQuery)) {          
    $query .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
    $handle = $this->link->prepare($query);
    $handle->execute($insertData);
  }
}
```