# Mysql SELECT function returning unkonwn column error in field list

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code and I can't figure out the error within the code as it seems perfectly written by me. 
This is the code...

```
function add_product_to_cart($pdo, $table, $cart_id, $product_id, $attributes){
    $parameters = [':product_id' => $product_id, ':attributes' => $attributes];

    #$addProduct = ' DECLARE productQuantity INT; ';
    #$addProduct = 'SELECT @cart := ' . $cart_id;
    $addProduct = 'SET @cart := ' . $cart_id . ';';
    $addProduct .= 'SELECT  * FROM `' . $table . '` WHERE cart_id = @cart AND product_id = :product_id';
    $addProduct .= ' AND attributes = :attributes ';
    $addProduct .= 'IF @cart IS NULL THEN INSERT INTO `' . $table . '`(';
    $addProduct .= 'cart_id, product_id, attributes, quantity, added_on) VALUES (';
    $addProduct .= '@cart, :product_id, :attributes, 1, 1, NOW())';
    $addProduct .= ' ELSE UPDATE `' . $table . '` SET quantity = quantity + 1, buy_now = true WHERE cart_id = @cart';
    $addProduct .= ' AND product_id = :product_id AND attributes = :attributes';
    query($pdo, $addProduct, $parameters);
    return $query;
}
```

and this is the error

> Unable to connect to the database server: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column '3ab31dbf3ced5f2c4df0b739e740110f' in
>   'field list' in

What I want to do is actually check if the cart_id is save in the database and if it is save, update the quqntity in the database and if not insert it into the database.

The unknown column it complained about is the value and the column to search against is the cart_id

Comment: You're missing a `;` on the end of this line: `$addProduct .= ' AND attributes = :attributes ';` i.e. it should be `$addProduct .= ' AND attributes = :attributes;';`

Comment: This is doing a lot of things. I would rather create a stored procedure

Comment: Are you trying to do an insert/update depending on existing data - you might be better off with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383503/on-duplicate-key-update-same-as-insert/14383597.

Comment: @Nick is still the same

Comment: @NigelRen you got it. That is what I want to do

Comment: @Cid so many technologies to learn, so I don't see the reason to learn stored procedure.

Comment: What is the value of `$product_id`?

Comment: @gbengawale this will leave the logic behind that update process to the DB. This way, if you have differents applications using that DB, You won't have to re-write the whole query for each application. Especially if you change the SQL code, you won't have to re-change it everywhere. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @Adder it is taken from the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commendted by [Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren), this is a good spot to take advantage of [MySQL `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEYS` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

For this to work, you just need to create a unique constraint on columns `(cart_id, product_id)`.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT my_table_constraint UNIQUE (cart_id, product_id);
```

Note that, to create the constraint, the existing data must be compliant (ie you cannot create it if you already have duplicates in the table, you need to delete them first).

Now, you whole code can be simplified using the followinq query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
    (cart_id, product_id, attributes, quantity, added_on) 
    VALUES (:cart, :product_id, :attributes, 1, 1, NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEYS UPDATE quantity = quantity + 1, buy_now = true
```

If you try to insert on an already existing `(cart_id, product_id)` tuple, then MySQL automatically skips the insert and executes the update command described in the the `ON DUPLICATE KEYS` clause.

On top of making your code shorter and simpler, another benefit of this syntax is that is effectively protects you against race conditions: with your existing code, there is always a possibility that two processes running concurrently would insert duplicate records, whereas when using the above, data integrity is guaranteed by MySQL.

The only donwside is that the contraints applies to all operations executed againts the table, it is not localized to a specific part of the code.