# Codeigniter 4 update into database with save()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I tried to update into my database by using save(). As my primary key is an auto increment id, it creates a new row when I tried to use save().

I tried to use save($game_id, $newData) for testing and I got error message.

Below is my code :

Table add_game

```
id | game_id | user_id | ign  | acc_id
1  | 3       | 1       | ignA | accA
2  | 3       | 1       | ignB | accB
3  | 3       | 1       | ignC | accC
```

Model

```
protected $table = 'add_game';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'user_id',
        'game_id',
        'ign',
        'acc_id'
    ];
```

Controller

```
$newData = [
                    'user_id' => session()->get('user_id'),
                    'game_id' => $game_id,
                    'ign' => $this->request->getVar('ign'),
                    'acc_id' => $this->request->getVar('acc_id')
                ];
    
                $model->save($newData); // currently it keeps creating new record
                $model->save($newData); // return me error message
```

How do I update my existing records? I want to update them base on my user_id as well as game_id. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: At the very least, you need to post what the error actually is and this table's actual schema (not example rows, how the table is actually defined) for it to be possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

in codeigniter 4 `save()` method can do insert and update depend on data you provide

in your table if u want to update to **add_game** table u just add the **id** of data you want to update

```
$newData = [
           'id' => 1 //add data id here
           'user_id' => session()->get('user_id'),
           'game_id' => $game_id,
           'ign' => $this->request->getVar('ign'),
           'acc_id' => $this->request->getVar('acc_id')
           ];
    
$model->save($newData);
```

Comment: Hi Nadim, yes I know about the ID thingy but the thing is because I do not know which ID so my update condition is based on user id and game id.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a primary key defined to make `save()` work for updating. In your example this primary key should/must be `id`:

> save()
>
> This is a wrapper around the insert() and update() methods that handle
> inserting or updating the record automatically, based on whether it
> finds an array key matching the $primaryKey value:

as you don't mention the id, obviously a new record is inserted and not updated.

in order to update, you need to supply that unique $primaryKey:

```
// Performs an update on id=3, since the primary key, 'id', is found.
$newData = [
    'id'       => 3,
    'user_id' => session()->get('user_id'),
    'game_id' => $game_id,
    'ign' => $this->request->getVar('ign'),
    'acc_id' => $this->request->getVar('acc_id')
];
$model->save($newData);
```

no need to repeat last line (`$model->save($newData);`), that's always calling for trouble/error

from the CI 4.x docs: [Saving Data](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=save#saving-data)

an important read to understand the underlying SQL query you find here: [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14383597/2275490) and https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/ among many others

Comment: Hi Vickel, I understand that I need to have a primary key defined. I have to update based on the user_id and game_id in order to update accordingly, so I can't define a primary key. Is there a way to do it using save()? Or I can only use update()?

Comment: id in table add_game seems to be unique, change it to primary key in your phpMyAdmin of cPanel. Also save() is used for insert (new row) or update(existing row), if you are only updating, never inserting, use update() obviously

Comment: Just curious and off topic, since most application only either insert() or update() so in what kind of scenario can we use save()? I can't really think of any.

Comment: Imagine you have a new user and edit user form. This form could be the same. When you fill out the data with name email, etc. and set email as unique index, then it will either insert a new user, if email doesn't exist or update the user with the matching email. If you read through the links in my answer, there you find the underlying sql queries

Comment: I see. Noted on that, still can't really visualize though but will look at those examples. Thank you!

Comment: Any CMS (content management system) would use insert on duplicate update. The admin creates (inserts) the user, the user updates his data (except the data of the primary key, which could be an ID or an email or anything else unique, of course)

Comment: no primary key necessarily, with a whereIn clause you reduce the data set to the one(s) you want to update (if more than one row matches the where clause, all those rows get updated): see last example of update() here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=flexible%20solution#saving-data

Comment: or you switch to update method from query builder class: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update#updating-data. Anyway, in my answer I tried to respond to your original question, did that work out?

Comment: I don't understand what does the set active do though. I tried to use that method previously but it returns me an error "There is no data to {0}." I tried to do it another way which I am not sure whether is this the right way to do it but it works. $userCond = $model->where('user_id', session()->get('user_id'))->where('game_id', $game_id)->first(); and then $model->update($userCond, $newData);

Comment: that's the query builder classic way, perfect to update. Use it. It wouldn't "insert on duplicate update", which was your original question about save(), but if you only want to update, it's the classic way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem for me too..
If u have custome 'id' name, u must define it with:

```
$primaryKey ="custom_id"
$useAutoIncrement = false
```

and you must include your custom_id in AllowedField :

```
$allowedFelds = [
"custom_id",  // you must include it
"foo",
"bar"
]
```

Comment: Avoid using Internet dialects -> Use "you" instead of "u".