# Codeigniter 4 'update' from Controller

Tags: codeigniter, controller, sql-update, query-builder, codeigniter-4

I'm so confused...

This function runs OK and doesn't throw up any errors... but it doesn't update the row in my table.

Where have I gone wrong?

Controller:

```
    public function update()
    {     
        $model = new StoreModel();
      
        $model->where('merchant', 'Klip Shop')->set('availability', 'out of stock')->update();
        
    }
```

Model:

```
class StoreModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'shop';
}
```

Comment: does `$model->where('merchant', 'Klip Shop')->get()` return anything?

Comment: [@Vickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275490/vickel) Nothing. Not even "NULL" when I `var_dump` it.

Comment: I've update my answer, after looking into your controller and model, hope this will work now

Answer (score 1):

Since `$model->where('merchant', 'Klip Shop')->get()` doesn't return anything, it means that you don't have any data you can update.

You need to insert a row first.

1. you could use the insert() function, if there is no rows detected
   with the merchant name

or

2. there is the save() function in CI 4.x which either inserts or
   updates on duplicate. but to get it to work, you need to set
   merchant to unique or use a column with an unique key

please read: [Saving Data in CI 4.x](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=save#saving-data)

**edit:** you actually got me confused too:

only now I analized your MCV code:

you should have a controller

```
public function update()
{     
    $model = new StoreModel();
    $model->update();
}
```

and a model:

```
class StoreModel extends Model
{
    $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
    $model= $db->table('shop');

    function update(){
        $model->where('merchant', 'Klip Shop')->set('availability', 'out of stock')->update();
    }
}
```

Comment: [@Vickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275490/vickel) THAT'S why I'm so confused... there's literally THOUSANDS of matching entries in my database to update. No spelling mistakes or anything.

Comment: can you create a small sqlfiddle? something like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/1

Comment: [@Vickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275490/vickel) This is it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf443f Thank you for all your help!

Comment: check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52bc7f/1: the left hand panel now updates your existing merchant, if you change the merchant's name to one, which doesn't exist, it cannot update and give an error, therefor the CI 4.x save() function, which practically generates this SQL:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14383597/2275490

Comment: [@Vickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275490/vickel) Thank you for all the time you’re spending helping me with this. It’s really appreciated!

Isn’t what you’ve coded in MySQL the same as what I originally coded for my Controller though? What I’ve coded for my Controller isn’t updating the data but it looks like the same logic as yours... What do I need to change in my Controller to do the update?

Comment: I've added the line `UPDATE shop SET availability = 'not in stock' WHERE merchant = 'Notino.co.uk'`at the left hand side, therefore if you run the query (Run SQL) you'll see the updated output. But yes it is following the sample you gave. Use `echo $model->getCompiledSelect();` and see the generated SQL

Comment: [@Vickel]() Isn't this (your code): `UPDATE shop SET availability = 'not in stock' WHERE merchant = 'Notino.co.uk'` the same as (my code): `$model->where('merchant', 'Notino.co.uk')->set('availability', 'not in stock')->update();`? The latter isn't updating my database. I understand the MySQL code/logic behind what I'm trying to do, but I need to do it in a Query Builder Class function in a Controller as it's not a one-off task.

Comment: no, because you query for "Klip Shop", with  ` $model->where('merchant', 'Klip Shop')->set('availability', 'out of stock')->update();` and not for Notino.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

It was an `$allowedFields` issue with the model, hence nothing was 'allowed' to be updated.